# Will Xcode 6.0.1 under 10.9.5 automatically sign my applications with the new „Version 2 Signatures“?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode6, code-signing, xcode5.1

I started my project with Xcode 5.1.1 under 10.9.4. I let Xcode generate all the necessary identities and profiles and do the code signing. Will Xcode 6.0.1 under 10.9.5 automatically sign my applications with the new, „Version 2 Signatures“?

Or do i have to manually change something for these new signatures come into effect? If so, what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Version 2 signatures are automatically created when building under OS X 10.9.x or greater.   (See Apple's Tech Note [TN2206](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html)).   The code signer is built into the OS and is independent of Xcode, which is why you can't get a version 2 signature from a prior version of OS X.  (Note that 10.9.x or greater actually put a Version 1 and Version 2 signature in there because they are created differently and the Version 1 must exist for use under 10.8.x).

To verify you have the right signature, use the command `codesign -dv <your app bundle>`.    Look for the `Sealed Resources` line which should have a version number on it.